# Having trouble trying to add a line to a text file if that line doesn't exist already using Python fileinput.FileInput(...)

Tags: python, writetofile, file-io

I'm trying to edit text files using the Python FileInput class.  First I store the lines that i need to write in a Dictionary.  Then I iterate through that dictionary, and if the dictionary[key] matches any line in that line, I replace the line with the dictionary key-value pair. If the dictionary[key] does not exist in the file, then I want to write that line at the end of the file; however, this last part is not working and is not writing to file.

Here is what the current code looks like:

def file_edit(properties, dst_path):

```
for key in properties.iterkeys():
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(dst_path, inplace=1):
        if str(key) + '=' in line:                      #<==== This works    
            print key + '=' + properties[key]           #<==== This works
        #The below condition checks that if the Dictionary[Key] is not there, then just print the line
        elif str(key) + '=' not in line and re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9=:]+',line) is not None:
            print line.strip()              #<==== This seems to work
        else:                                      #<============THIS DOES NOT WORK
            print key + '=' + properties[key]      #<============THIS DOES NOT WORK
    fileinput.close()
```

file_edit( {'new key': 'some value', 'existing key': 'new value'}, SomeTextFile.TXT)

Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall()` will never return None, if there are no matches it will return an empty list.  Because of this your first `elif` will always be true.  You should be using `re.search()` instead (since you aren't using the result of `findall()` anyway):

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9=:]+', "(>'_')>")
[]
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9=:]+', "(>'_')>") is not None
True
>>> re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9=:]+', "(>'_')>")
None
>>> re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9=:]+', "(>'_')>") is not None
False
```